# What tensorflow distribution to represent a list of categorical data

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I want to construct a variational autoencoder where one sample is an N*M matrix where for each row, there are M categories. Essentially one sample is a list of categorical data where only one category can be selected - a list of one-hot vectors.

Currently, I have a working autoencoder for this type of data - I use a softmax on the last dimension to create this constraint and it works (reconstruction cross entropy is low).

Now, I want to use tf.distributions to create a variational autoencoder. I was wondering what kind of distribution would be appropriate.

Comment: I do not understand what exactly your question is. Usually you want the latent vectors to be unit Gaussian. So you would use [tf.distributions.Normal](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/distributions/Normal) to sample such vectors.

Comment: For example in the MNIST dataset, the probability distribution of a single pixel can be represented using a Bernoulli distribution. Then to construct the decoder part of the variational autoencoder, the latent variables (in normal distribution as you mentioned) are the input and outputs 784 Bernoulli outcomes. In my case, the outcomes arent just 2 categories, but n>2 categories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does tf.contrib.distributions.Categorical satisfy your needs? Samples should be from (0 to n - 1), where n represents the category.

Example:

# logits has shape [N, M], where M is the number of classes

dist = tf.contrib.distributions.Categorical(logits=logits)

# Sample 20 times. Should give shape [20, N].

samples = dist.sample(20)

# depth is the number of categories.

one_hots = tf.one_hot(samples, depth=M)